# Why is the output different for the "with" function in r?

Tags: r

When I type this code:
`with(my.data, order(age))` I get the following output:`2 3 5 1 4`
but when I type this code:
`my.data[order(my.data$age),]` I get the following output:

```
  name age hgt  wgt  race year  SAT
2 Fred  18  67  156 Af.Am   Fr 1210
3 Barb  18  64  128  <NA>   Fr  840
5 Jeff  20  72  202 Asian   So  880
1  Bob  21  70  180  Cauc   Jr 1080
4  Sue  24  66 1118  Cauc   Sr   NA
```

I want to show the above output with the "with" function but it only gives me the first row and not the entire matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get that output, then you need to use `[]` in the statement.

```
with(my.data, my.data[order(age), ])
```

Output (just sample data with a few columns)

```
  name age hgt
2 Fred  18  67
3 Barb  18  64
5 Jeff  20  72
1  Bob  21  70
4  Sue  24  66
```

Sample Data

```
my.data <-
  structure(list(
    name = c("Bob", "Fred", "Barb", "Sue", "Jeff"),
    age = c(21, 18, 18, 24, 20),
    hgt = c(70, 67, 64, 66, 72)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,
                -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

`with` is used for convenience i.e. to avoid typing `my.data$` or `my.data[[` multiple times

```
with(my.data, order(age))
```

is equivalent to

```
order(my.data$age)
```

---

`with` is mostly useful when we do something like

```
with(my.data, order(name, age, hgt))
```

The equivalent will be `my.data$` repeated three times

```
order(my.data$name, my.data$age, my.data$hgt)
```

---

All of the above returns the `order` based index, which we use as row index in `[` (`?Extract`)

---

If we want to return the data, why not use `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
my.data %>%
     arrange(age)
```